# None of the methods showed favicon in safari for React application

Tags: reactjs, favicon

I have the following in index.html

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
```

None of them seems to have an effect, for some reason it still shows the react default icon.

How to fix?

In the html, it renders as

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png">
```

Comment: If you view the resulting HTML, what's actually getting rendered?

Comment: hey, @erotsppa did you try to clear the cache of the browser? If that doesn't work try to give full path to href...

Comment: What do you see if you go to `/favicon.ico` in the browser?

Comment: @ceejayoz The correct image. Also cache was cleared